# How to pad a formatted string

Tags: java

This may seem as a simple problem, but I honestly didn't seem to work this out.
I have a formatted string as follows:

```
String msg = String.format("Current player: %1$s", status.getCurrentPlayer().getName());
```

and I want to left-pad it, lets say with 10 spaces. I tried:

```
String pad = String.format("%1$10s", msg);
```

but it doesn't seem to work, although I tried it with an unformatted string:

```
String pad = String.format("%1$10s", "some string");
```

and obviousely, it worked.
What is it about "msg" that does not let me pad it?

Comment: `$10` allows for 10 spaces. It doesn't pad with 10 spaces.

Comment: In other words, `"Current pl"` itself is ten characters. Anything longer is not padded

Comment: ohhhh so $x gives x spaces in total. I didn't get that before. Thank you.

Comment: Just the `x`, not the `$`. The positioning is `1$`. The formatter is started with `%` and the string conversion is just `s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is it about "msg" that does not let me pad it?

It's longer than 10 characters.

That `10` is the *width* of the [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class.

Reading that documentation, you'll see

> The optional *width* is a non-negative decimal integer indicating the minimum number of characters to be written to the output.

So, minimum, meaning any string longer than that are printed as-is.

If you want to pad, just add 10 to the length of the string.

```
String msg = "some really, really long message";
String fmt = "%1$" + (10 + msg.length()) + "s";
String pad = String.format(fmt, msg);
// "          some really, really long message"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String msg = "Current player: " 
           + status.getCurrentPlayer().getName() 
           + new String(new char[10]).replace('\0', ' ');
```

This will add 10 spaces after the name of the player. If you want to take into account the length of the player name you can do this:

```
String msg = "Current player: " 
             + status.getCurrentPlayer().getName() 
             + new String(new 
                   char[10 - status.getCurrentPlayer().getName().Length ]).replace('\0', ' ');
```